# Simple dynamic hyperlink

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to see JR create, if possible, a dynamic (for lack of a better term known to me) hyperlink:

This is the sql query which fetches the data:

```
select name,ID
from table
where condition1=65537;
```

What I want JR to do is to change the hyperlink reference expression which is initially:
"https://www.some_site.com/item=X"

X
needs to be the ID number and be able to be parsed as a normal link

I tried the more obvious ideas:

```
X=$F{ID} /// doesn't work
X=$F{ID}.intValue() /// doesn't work
```

Is it:
a) even possible?
b) if possible, how?

I might be missing something very obvious, so apologies if this is something already addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the possible spam

"https://www.some_site.com/ID="+$F{ID}

is now the hyperlink reference expression and it all works out, in all possible export formats of jasper